# How to take image in my application and save the image in IOS?

Tags: ios, image, file, camera, photo

```
- (IBAction)btn_actionTakePicture:(UIButton *)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    //I want to know how to save the image into the UIImage *image = savingImage so that I can implement the next 2 lines

    UIImage *image = savingImage;
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

The last 2 lines of code depend upon getting the image which I snap to be saved inside the variable `savingImage`, so how do I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo.
From official documentation:

> To save a still image to the user’s Camera Roll album, call the UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum function from within the body of the imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: method.

Read more at: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate_Protocol/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate/UIImagePickerControllerDelegate.html

Maybe something like this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
UIImage *img = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
}
```

Comment: i'm completely new to ios can you explain how to implement `info`

Comment: Check out the official tutorial code as already mentioned by Sam - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/photopicker/Introduction/Intro.html - you can even download the whole project and see how it works in action (there is no other functionality in that code so it should be easy to navigate and understand). Also, for all the explanations of how it works, please read the documentation on that page.

Answer (score -1):

You need to remove these two lines from your IBAction and add this function

```
//UIImage *image = savingImage;
//UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
```

PS. Your UIImagePickerController *picker needs to be global
You maybe missing a whole lot of other stuff. Take a look at Apple's sample code https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/photopicker/Introduction/Intro.html

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
      didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *)image
                 editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo
{

    NSLog(@"didFinishPickingImage ...");

    [picpicker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

    //save this image
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);

}
```

Comment: didFinishPickingImage is deprecated since iOS 3.0, I wouldn't use it. See my post below for more up to date implementation.